# Jquery Sparklines showing Wrong format on tooltip for negative values

Tags: sparklines

I am using this jquery plugin to show a sparkline, http://www.omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline.

Works perfectly except when there is a negative value on the linevalues, it shows "-,299" instead of "-299" only, I am trying to trace what's with all that comma still appending even if the value is in hundreds only.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alfdc/u8pyg/

HTML:

```
<div class="sparkslim" linevalues="69,1198,1076,545,447,-182,195,0,276,199,-312,187,713,508,2088,28947,33595,34587,19261,58,202,277,194,974"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".sparkslim").sparkline('html', {type: 'line', tagValuesAttribute: 'linevalues', 
width: "135",
    height: "25",
    lineColor: "#adadad",
    fillColor: "rgba(244, 252, 225, 0.0)",
    lineWidth: 2,
    spotColor: "#909090",
    minSpotColor: "#909090",
    maxSpotColor: "#909090",
    highlightSpotColor: "#666",
    highlightLineColor: "#666",
    spotRadius: 0,
    chartRangeMin: 0,
    tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} : {{y:val}}',
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in internal function number formatNumber.
I resolve it with setting custom numberFormatter. It should look like this:

```
$(".sparkslim").sparkline('html', {
     ...
     numberFormatter: function(x) { return x; },
     ...
});
```

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/u8pyg/1/